# How to integrate OpenCL with OpenJDK?

Tags: java, opencl

I'm working on a project, where I require to use OpenCL run on OpenJDK for some task (GC related).

I was able to integrate the OpenCL library to the OpenJDK source code and build it successfully. But most of the OpenCL codes use vector datatype which is not supported by OpenJDK.

How can I run a simple OpenCL code inside OpenJDK?.

I'm able to include OpenCL library

```
#define CL_USE_DEPRECATED_OPENCL_1_2_APIS
#define CL_TARGET_OPENCL_VERSION 110
#include <CL/cl.hpp>
```

But declaring something like this gives an error.

```
std::vector<int> testVector;
```

I was also checking the OpenCL integration with OpenJDK and came across this particular link
`https://openjdk.java.net/projects/sumatra/`  and  there they have mentioned ***Rootbeer - a compiler that makes it easier to program GPUs with Java*** but I was not able to load that.

Could someone please tell me if I can use OpenCL inside OpenJDK?.

Comment: IDK anything about anything Java, but it looks like your problem is with C++ vector type in the C++ OpenCL interface. Is it possible to use the regular C OpenCL interface? Can you just replace CL/cl.hpp with CL/cl.h? (Assuming your OpenCL library has the C files alongside the c++ files)